# After update: getting error related to ROS_ROOT and rosbash

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting this error after the update.

bash: /share/rosbash/rosbash: No such file or directory 
ROS_ROOT=/share/ros: No such file or directory

Please tell me how to overcome that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86981/after-update:-getting-error-related-to-ros_root-and-rosbash/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-03**:
Note related and/or duplicate question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/86586/ros-groovy-update-screwed-up-workspace-setup-in-some-cases/

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-10-03**:
I agree Stefan Kohlbrecher and got to visit question posted by you just after posting it here. But i do not know what to do. I admit your words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just getting this error also,

bash: /share/rosbash/rosbash: No such file or directory

I actually just reinstalled groovy, but pointed it to an old catkin_ws in my bashrc.  I ended up doing a catkin_make in my catkin_ws and it cleaned up the error.  I am not sure if this will help, but saw your post as I was trying to figure out my issue, so figured I'd let you know of a potential fix to your problem.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-10-03**:
It worked. I just changed directory to catkin work space and run the catkin_make and it all gone well.